# Return bean-type transaction to queue

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, java-ee-6

We have an application deployed to a glassfish server with an MDB that, for other reasons, must use Bean-type transactions (TransactionManagementType.BEAN).

In certain situations, inside the onMessage() method we'd like to be able to look at the message and refuse it. By "refuse" I mean put the message back on the queue and have it be re-delivered later.

I've searched around a bit but all that I've found seems to say that I should just change the transaction type to Container and call setRollbackOnly(). However, as I said above that's not an option due to other constraints.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried throwing an Exception?

Comment: Got pulled aside and haven't had the time yet to look, but will try an Exception next chance I get...

Comment: Throwing an exception doesn't put it back on the queue either.

Comment: Then I recommend to break up your logic, and create a new MDB with CMT - like a wrapper, `onMessage()` is enough. From the MDB you can still call the business logic in the current EJB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this:

http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/ejb/ejb3_mdb.htm

It says that in `Client-acknowledge` mode is not supported in MDB.

Answer (score 0):

Although it would be possible for the MDB to throw an exception and rollback the current transaction, forcing the caller to resend the message, there is no way for a bean managed transaction method to join an existing transaction. I think that to achieve such behavior you should implement a communication protocol between the sender and the receiver MDB, using a data store to model a message queue.

Comment: That's not true, if you use CMT, and mark the transaction for rollback, it will "return" the message to the queue, and will try to redeliver later. This comes from the transactional behavior. The question is, how could he "return" a message, if there is no transaction in progress.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that the delivery (`onMessage()` call) is not in transaction. If it were, it could have been rolled back.